# Is there a way to reset the google sheet on specific day of the week without reseting the outcome value in one cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a budget/expense sheet. I want to have the sheet reset every Sunday at 11:59 pm, except for the current balance cell ( let's call the current balance cell **CB** ).

The initial **CB** value will be entered by the user the first time, and I want the **CB** cell automatically update the value every week by calculating the Total Income and expenses of the week.

I trying to make the sheet reset at a specific time of the day, and bring forward the previous calculations in the **CB** cell every week.

I've tried recording Macro but it didn’t work

Comment: Hi there @ParamjeetSingh! I could show you how to run this operation easily on [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) triggers. Would that be a valid answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating a trigger Programmatically

```
function createTrigger(funcname) {
  //the conditional insures that you never create more than one trigger which can create problems that are difficult to debug
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == funcname).length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY).atHour(23).nearMinute(45).create();//You cannot specify a time any more accurately
  }
}
```